# jackson bi-directional mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a oneToMany bi-direction relationship between a parent and it's children, 2 jsp page to display the data. for the parent page, it shows the parents and underlying children. and in the child page, it shows the child and its parent. so I need a bi-direction structure.

Parent page:  Parent to child
child page:   Child to parent

I use jackson and try to use @JsonBackReference, but this actually skip a one way relationship. what's the right way to do this? I know if I only set one way relation it can work. but because I use jpa and need to load the data in both way. it means  I have to trim down one way after I load it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to (de)serialize a cyclic graph without going in an "infinite loop".

The [@JsonIdentityInfo](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) annotation is quite nice for that, but I guess it wouldn't work within a JSP: you're probably loading JSON data with AJAX and I think JSON.parse() doesn't support object references.

Or you could use [a custom serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers). As far as I know, there's no simple way to give Jackson information on the serialization context; one could achieve that using [Jackson Value Injection](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureValueInjection) or storing data in a ThreadLocal.